# How can I eject the CD-ROM drive with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: windows, disk, cd-rom, naturallyspeaking

Is there any way to eject  the CD-ROM drive with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [Windows Multimedia API (also known as WinMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_legacy_audio_components):

```
' From Larry Allen
' https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=12&threadid=12153&highlight_key=y&keyword1=eject
' http://archive.is/Y2ouS
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
Declare Sub mciSendStringA Lib "winmm.dll" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, _
ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Long, _
ByVal hWndCallback As Long)

Sub Main
Dim dummy As String
    mciSendStringA "Set CDAudio Door Open", dummy, 0, 0
End Sub
```

[source](https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=12&threadid=12153&highlight_key=y&keyword1=eject) ([mirror](http://archive.is/Y2ouS))